# Rails 3 - Link to :remote, updating the address URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm currently toying with updating page content via the following:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag(:span, 'Settings'), edit_admin_store_path, :remote => true)%>
```

With the javascript as such:

```
  $('nav li a').bind("ajax:success", function(event, data){
    console.log(event + data);
    $('div#loading').hide();
    $('div#container div#content').html(data).hide().fadeIn('100');
  });
```

And was wondering if there is a 'rails way' to also update the address url as well?

Thanks a plenty for any help/advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you are asking for the HTML5 history.pushState method. Great documentation can be found [here, at the mozilla developers network.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

To be simple, you would push into the history by doing something like this:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState( stateObj, "new page title", "forbear.html" )
```

This will cause the URL to display `http://www.yoursite.html/whatever/foobar.html` depending on what the URL currently looks like.

Cheers!

Comment: Are there any options that work pre HTML5? I'd be satisfied with adding in #hashes to the url, if the back button worked as well. 

How does this fit in with something like Pjax for example?

Comment: Ore HTML5, this was a very difficult task to achieve. Hence thus arriving in HTML5. you could add fragments to the URL, but you would need to manually update the DOM every time it was removed/changed. I do not recommend that. You would use history.js to automate the latter, instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. 

I ended up using PJAX and customising it to work nicely with rails. Thanks for your advice.