# How to solve the ajax back button in rails from link_to

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, back-button

I've got a rails 3 app with several `<%= link_to :remote=>true %>` that I'm using to load partials via the js.erb.  I'm now trying to add the back button functionality.

I've looked at tutorials like [railscast #246](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) and other StackOverflow questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597822/rails-3-link-to-remote-updating-the-address-url), but these approaches all assume that I have access to the javascript to do the page loads.  My js.erb's look like:

```
$('#leftside_buttons').html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'report_types') %>")
$('#titles').html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'titles') %>")
$('#data_display').html("<%= escape_javascript(render get_current_data_view) %>")

<% if @start_date.nil? %>
  $("#_start_date").datepicker("setDate", new Date("<%= @min_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>"))
<% else %>
  $("#_start_date").datepicker("setDate", new Date("<%= @start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>"))
<% end %>
<% if @end_date.nil? %>
  $("#_end_date").datepicker("setDate", new Date("<%= @max_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>"))
<% else %>
  $("#_end_date").datepicker("setDate", new Date("<%= @end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>"))
<% end %>
```

Which, really, isn't a whole lot of javascript.  The [Rails API documentation for link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) states that:

```
:remote => true - This will allow the unobtrusive JavaScript driver to make an Ajax request to the URL in question instead of following the link. The drivers each provide mechanisms for listening for the completion of the Ajax request and performing JavaScript operations once they’re complete
```

which leads me to believe that, because this style of ajax is using unobtrusive javascript, I can't get into the javascript to add on the history.pushState functionality that I think I need here.  What should I do to solve this back button problem when using this style of link_to?

Comment: Just out of interest have you configured your routes to handle this?

Comment: @David-- what do routes have to do with this?  None of the tutorials have mentioned have routes.

Comment: Usually if you are using ajax in a rails app you would configure your routes to handle the `post` request but in this case I guess you are not handling anything. Can also have a look at the following link if it helps - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Comment: @David-- that is actually super helpful, thanks!  I'm thinking of binding a history.pushState to ajax:success to this class of links (I've been pretty consistent throughout, luckily).  I'm not sure how routes enter into it yet though-- what did you have in mind?

Comment: mmr That was my fault. From my understanding you simply want to redirect back to a page which doesn't include you posting any information. So ignore my earlier comment regarding routes. I believe the only time you will need to configure your routes when using ajax is when you are making `get` or `post` request. Glad the link helped you out. Your way of thinking sounds like you are on the right track :)

Comment: Something like the following might be helpful for people coming across this question in the future. You can include the following in the JS for that particular route, or application.js:

`$(document).on('click', 'a[data-remote="true"]', function(e){
    history.pushState({}, '', $(e.target).attr('href'));
  });`